# Windows Phone Control displayed event

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, controls

Does it exist an event, which occur, when control is displayed in Parent Control? I have tryed LayoutUpdated and SizeChanged events but they occured before control had displayed.

Comment: Not enough information, need some more description.

Comment: Ok. For example, on some event I want to add Image to Grid.Children collection. But I need to do some others actions after Image has displayed. But I don't understand how can I handle this moment?

Comment: Can you try to do your stuff in Image_Loaded() event?

Comment: It doesn't work. Moreover, when Loaded event occured, controls properties ActualHeight and ActualWidth are equal to zero.